# Why can't I iterate over the array?

Tags: reactjs

Why can't I iterate over the array?

I try to use ***map***, but I get an error:

*`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userInfo.data.map')`*

Code:

```
userInfo.data.map(items => console.log(items))
```

userInfo.data:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting condition. if you are saving your data in `userInfo`

```
userInfo.data && userInfo.data.data.map(items => console.log(items))
```

otherwise

```
userInfo.data && userInfo.data.map(items => console.log(items))
```

If userInfo data available then only iterate.

Answer (score 0):

```
(userInfo.data || []).data.map(items => console.log(items))
```

try this maybe userInfo is null in 1st render

Answer (score 0):

If the screenshot shows the structure of `userInfo.data`, then you must use `userInfo.data.data.map`. Otherwise use `userInfo.data && userInfo.data.map(...`.